# how can i pass my string to the email intent service?

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

```
gen_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        String to = text.getText().toString().trim();
        String subject = text2.getText().toString().trim();
        String content = text3.getText().toString().trim();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,to );
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(email);

        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new  MultiFormatWriter();

        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix =  multiFormatWriter.encode(
                email.getAction(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 250, 250
            );
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder=new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        catch (WriterException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

i want to generate an email, as you can see, i got three edit text(**to, subject, content**) and i already insert the **email intent**, when i generate it catch all the string and i send the string through email app, but the problem is, all of my string does not get to their respective email format. where did i do wrong? sorry if you cant understand what i am asking all i can do is to show my code. i am new to android java so please help.

Comment: `the problem is, all of my string does not get the email format.` What does this mean ?

Comment: the string does not get to their respective email format like email,subject and body.

Comment: what does it get ?

Comment: all of the string go to email 'To' textbox and my string subject and content suppose go to the 'subject' and 'body' email app textbox.

Comment: Your variable `to` should be pass as String array, use as this  `email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,  new String[]{to});`

Comment: just add  string array?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are trying to send email through the email app. This might be helpful.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Comment: whre should i put this code ? in the multiformatwriter or gen_btn.setOnclicklistener?